# How to write correctly complex query with multiple includes in Sequlize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm new in Sequelize ORM. I have the tables user, role and vote.

I want to get a single user with his role (maybe few) and average of rate from vote table as rating field. I am stuck with a `group by` problem.

```
const id = req.params.id;
user
.findOne({
  where: { id },
  attributes: [
    "id",
    "username",
    "email",
    "avatar",
    "createdAt",
  ],
  include: [
    { model: role, attributes: ["name"] },
    { model: vote, attributes: ["rate"] },
  ],
})
.then(user => {
  res.status(200).json({ user });
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

the code above get next json

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "username": "John Connor",
  "email": "johny@gmail.com",
  "avatar": "/public/static/img/uploads/avatar.jpg",
  "createdAt": "2018-03-05T20:25:56.693Z",
  "role": {
    "name": "USER_ROLE"
  },
  "votes": [
    {
      "rate": 4
    },
    {
      "rate": 5
    },
    {
      "rate": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know how to do that complex query right and get average of
instead of getting all fields rate. How you do queries like this?
Maybe I should do this separately or kind of different?

Comment: Note: `user` and `role`are keywords in (postgres)SQL. Better not use them as identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

```
user.findOne({
    where: { id },
    attributes: [
        "id",
        "username",
        "email",
        "avatar",
        "createdAt",
        [sequelize.fn('AVG', sequelize.col('votes.rate')) ,'average_vote'] // perform average function like this
    ],
    include: [
        { model: role, attributes: ["id","name"] },
        { model: vote, attributes: [] }, // remove all the attributes from vote model
    ],
    // group by by the rest 2 table's (change user. and role. as per table name or query)
    group : ['user.id','role.id']

})
```

> Note :
>
> 1. Please read the comments in code
> 2. There might be table name issue so you need to check that , rest of the part will work 100% fine.

Comment: will "group : [ 'role.id']" not affect on result if user will have a few roles ?

Comment: I dont think so.

Comment: it asks me to add "votes.id" to group [ ] and then show me 1 rate of 3 without applying AVG

Comment: @SergeyShiryaev , please check `attributes: []` is blank inside vote

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const id = req.params.id;
user
.findOne({
  where: { id },
  attributes: [
    "id",
    "username",
    "email",
    "avatar",
    "createdAt",
  ],
  include: [
    { model: role, attributes: ["name"] },
    { model: vote, attributes: [[sequelize.fn('avg', sequelize.col('rate')), 'rate']] },
  ],
group: ['id', 'username', 'email', 'avatar', 'createdAt', 'name'],
})
.then(user => {
  res.status(200).json({ user });
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: after i add in group all filds this return 
votes":[{"rate":"5.0000000000000000"},{"rate":"4.0000000000000000"},{"rate":"2.0000000000000000"}]